Integrate $\frac{\sin2x+2}{\sin2x+\cos2x+1}$ with respect to $x$
Find the value of  $$\int\cfrac{\sin2x+2}{\sin2x+\cos2x+1}dx$$
My attempt at the solution:
$$\int\cfrac{\sin x\  \cos x+\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x}dx$$
$$x+\int{\frac{\tan^2x}{\tan x+1}dx}$$
$$x+\int{\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan x+1}-\frac{1}{1+\tan x}dx}$$
$$x+\ln(\tan x+1)-\int\frac{1}{1+\tan x}dx$$
No further could I solve.
PS
This is part of a longer question (multiple correct type)


https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-integrate-1-1-tanx-dx

Or MathSE thread on $\int \frac1{1+\tan x},dx$.

From the starting, substitute $u=  \tan x$ and convert the problem into a partial fraction question. A little long but always works.

$\ln(\tan(3\pi/4)+1)$ is undefined.

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\tan x}dx=\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)+(\cos x+\sin x)}{\sin x+\cos x}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\sin x+\cos x|+x+c$$

Alternatively
\begin{align}
& \int\cfrac{\sin2x+2}{\sin2x+\cos2x+1}dx\\
=&\int\cfrac{\sin x\  \cos x+1}{\cos x(\sin x+\cos x)}dx
=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\frac{  \cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx\\
= &\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\frac12+ \frac12\frac{  \cos x-\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx\\
=& \ \frac12x -\ln|\cos x|+ \frac12\ln|\sin x+\cos x|+C
\end{align}

Alternatively,$$\int\cfrac{\sin2x+2}{\sin2x+\cos2x+1}dx=\int\cfrac{\sin x\  \cos x+1}{\cos x(\sin x+\cos x)}dx$$$$=\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx+\int\frac{1}{\cos x(\sin x+\cos x)}dx$$$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(\sin x+\cos x)-(\cos x-\sin x)}{\sin x+\cos x}dx+\int\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan x+1}dx$$$$=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln|\sin x+\cos x|+\ln|\tan x+1|+c$$$$=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln|\sin x+\cos x|-\ln|\cos x|+c$$
